# How to graph the total frequency as a percentage of population based off of gender?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

So I want to take the given code below and divide each gender by the genders total population (F is 5018 and M is 5827) so that I get the marks as a percentage of it's gendered population. Which will make the outcome more accurate as otherwise M mark rate is always higher because it's population is higher.

I have included the code below... I am getting stuck into where I need to divide it by its total population. There are so many ways to go and I am confused which one is the most simple.

```
 # to give the count of the number of M and F in data total no of students is 10,845
# project2data %>% group_by(project2data$Gender) %>% summarise(Gender_count=n())
# in graph frequency of females has to be divided by 5018 and males by 5827

for (row in 1:nrow(project2data)) {
  mark = project2data[row, 8]
  
  if (mark >= 0 && mark < 50) {
    project2data[row, 27] = '0 - 49: Fail '
  } else if (mark >= 50 && mark < 65) {
    project2data[row, 27] = ' 50 - 64 : Pass'
  } else if (mark >= 65 && mark < 75) {
    project2data[row, 27] = ' 65 - 74: Credit'
  } else if (mark >= 75 && mark < 85) {
    project2data[row, 27] = ' 74 - 84 : Distinction'
  } else if (mark >= 75 && mark < 101) {
    project2data[row, 27] = ' 85 - 100: High Distinction'
  }
}

gender_mark = table(project2data$V27, project2data$Gender)
gender_mark
```

This produces the following

[image: Image of gender_mark]

So each of these rows I want to divide by its respective gendered population.
Here is my coding for ggplot

```
gm = as.data.frame(gender_mark)

g2 = ggplot(gm, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq, fill = Var2)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) + ggtitle('Marks by Gender') + labs(x = 'Mark Ranges', y = 'Percentage of Population') + guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Gender')) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6, angle = 0)) + scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=4, name="GrandBudapest2")) +theme(title = element_text(size = 10))

g2
```

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I can't include the data due to privacy limitations. I was hoping I had included enough information that someone could suggest a way of solving the question. There is a column within project2data that is titled gender and states whether gender is male or female (does that help).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sweep` to divide each value by the sum of the column.

```
result <- sweep(gender_mark, 2, colSums(gender_mark), `/`)
```

Or with transpose :

```
result <- t(t(gender_mark)/colSums(gender_mark))
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting your table to a data.frame you can add a column with the proportions using e.g. `tapply` or using `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::mutate`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)
library(dplyr)

gm <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c('0 - 49: Fail ', ' 50 - 64 : Pass', ' 65 - 74: Credit', ' 74 - 84 : Distinction', ' 85 - 100: High Distinction'),
  Var2 = rep(c("F", "M"), each = 5),
  Freq = c(1493, 1411, 1199, 369, 546, 1630, 1703, 1314, 474, 706)
)

# base R
gm$prop <- gm$Freq / tapply(gm$Freq, gm$Var2, sum)[gm$Var2]
# dplyr
gm <- gm %>% group_by(Var2) %>% mutate(prop = Freq / sum(Freq))

g2 <- ggplot(gm, aes(x = Var1, y = prop, fill = Var2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(n=4, name="GrandBudapest2")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title = 'Marks by Gender', x = 'Mark Ranges', y = 'Percentage of Population') + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Gender')) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6, angle = 0)) + 
  theme(title = element_text(size = 10))

g2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much this is exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you for taking time to help! I ended up using the mutate function as I have used that one before but the way you laid it out really helped.